# How to use a web proxy with HttpNtlmAuth - auth_header_value is negotiate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below. If I take out `, proxies=proxies` and try and connect to the Intranet, it works, I get a response back.

However if I try an external site with the above put in (as per my example below), I get a 407 error

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
proxies = {'http': 'http://myproxy.local:9090'}
ntlm_auth = HttpNtlmAuth('DomainName\\MyUsername','MyPassword')
res = requests.get("https://bbc.co.uk",auth=ntlm_auth, proxies=proxies)
print(res.content)
```

Am I doing something obviously incorrect? When I go to IE and look at the proxy information there, this is exactly what I am using

**UPDATE**

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
ntlm_auth = HttpNtlmAuth("DomainName\\MyUsername","MyPassword")
proxies = {'http': 'http://myproxy.local:9090'}

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies
s.auth = ntlm_auth

res = s.get("http://bbc.co.uk")
print(res.content)
```

I get the following:

[image]

When outputting the value of `auth_header_value` I get `negotiate`